# How can I dynamically change property value in an object in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I have property named `listItem` in `useStyles` defined outside of `TodoListItem` like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
        listItem: {
            textDecoration: 'none'
        }
    })
)

const TodoListItem({checked}) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return <ListItemText className={classes.listItem} primary={text}/>
};
```

Then I wanted to change the status of `textDecoration` based on variable named `checked`.
And I tried to directly use `checked` variable in `useStyles` but does not work as it is out of scope.

```
textDecoration: checked ? 'line-through' : 'none'
```

In this case, how should I pass `checked` variable into `useStyles` to make the ternary operator working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CSS properties in `makeStyles` support custom props for dynamic styling:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    listItem: {
        textDecoration: ({checked}) => checked ? 'line-through' : 'none'
    }
}));

const Component = props => {
    const classes = useStyles({checked: props.checked});
    
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass `props`, `state`, and whatever you want as a param to the style hook.

And it has better readability since we can understand whether the style hook is using other params or not quickly.

```
const useStyles = checked =>
  makeStyles(theme => ({
    listItem: {
      textDecoration: checked ? 'line-through' : 'none'
    }
  }));
```

```
const classes = useStyles(checked)();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the most easy way to achieve it is to use `style` instead `classname` and manipulate everything that will use logic outside big style object

---

```
 <ListItemText style={[classes.listItem,{textDecoration: checked ? 'line-through' : 'none'}]} primary={text}/>
```

Comment: I agree that directly injecting style property is the most convenient way!